# transform move nodes with the same names into their parent nodes

Tags: xslt

the document to be transformed looks more or less like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <someCatalogProp>ąć</someCatalogProp>
  <meanProp>
           <node id="1">
    <someProperty>blabla1</someProperty>
    <children>
      <node idref="2"/>
    </children>
  </node>
  <node id="2">
    <someProperty>blabla2</someProperty>
    <children>
      <node idref="3"/>
    </children>
  </node>
  </meanProp>
  <node id="1">
    <someProperty>blabla1</someProperty>
    <children>
      <node idref="2"/>
    </children>
  </node>
  <node id="2">
    <someProperty>blabla2</someProperty>
    <children>
      <node idref="3"/>
    </children>
  </node>
  <node id="3">
    <someProperty>blabla3</someProperty>
    <children>
    </children>
  </node>
</root>
```

the result document should look like this:

```
<root>
<someCatalogProp>ąć</someCatalogProp>
    <node id = "1">
        <someProperty>blabla1</someProperty>
        <children>
             <node id = "2">
                 <someProperty>blabla2</someProperty>
                 <children>
                     <node id = "3">
                         <someProperty>blabla2</someProperty>
                         <children>
                         </children>
                     </node>
                </children>
            </node>
        </children>
    </node>
</root>
```

the number of children can be multiple. the depth of hierarchy is not limited.

How can the transformation xslt look like?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Re your new example: why is there no `meanProp` node in the output? Also, you have multiple `node` elements with the same id - that's **very** problematic, and your output does not provide a clue how to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite simple to accomplish using **[keys](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)**.

Provided you have a **well-formed** input such as:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <node id="1">
        <someProperty>blabla1</someProperty>
        <children>
             <node idref="2"/>
        </children>
    </node>
    <node id="2">
        <someProperty>blabla2</someProperty>
        <children>
             <node idref="3"/>
        </children>
    </node>
    <node id="3">
        <someProperty>blabla2</someProperty>
        <children>
        </children>
    </node>
</root>
```

applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="child" match="node" use="@id" />
<xsl:key name="parent" match="node" use="@idref" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node[not(key('parent', @id))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node[@idref]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', @idref)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <node id="1">
      <someProperty>blabla1</someProperty>
      <children>
         <node id="2">
            <someProperty>blabla2</someProperty>
            <children>
               <node id="3">
                  <someProperty>blabla2</someProperty>
                  <children/>
               </node>
            </children>
         </node>
      </children>
   </node>
</root>
```

Comment: I get pretty "random" results when other tags are present just under the root level, though, for example, above node id="1" there is <someCatalogProp>ab</someCatalogProp>

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a **representative** (and **well-formed**) input example.

Comment: I don't see any "random" results. The `someCatalogProp` node is missing from the output, that's all. If you want to include it, you can add `<xsl:apply-templates select="someCatalogProp"/>` to the template matching `root`.

Comment: I had some random results with bigger files as sometimes other nodes at the node level appeared and sometimes not depending on the test data. and how can I specify that generically, what if there is more than tags than somecatalologProp, some before nodes and some after? can I somehow preserve the other structure and deal only with the "node" elements?

Comment: You can do `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::node)]"/>`. To preserve the original order, combine the two: `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::node)] | node[not(key('parent', @id))]"/>`.

Comment: last question (even though I feel I push your patience a bit) - and what if only nodes at the level directly below the root are to be affected? I've added a "meanProp" tag that also contains nodes and idrefs but I'd like meanProp with what is in it completely unaffected. I tried `=*[node[not(key('parent', @id))]]` and `<xsl:template match="/mtCatalog/node[@idref]">` but this doesn't seem to do the trick yet.